# Not enough arguments for capability `setaf` in OpenBSD

Tags: colors, openbsd, tput

I want to change the text colour in a shell. I can use `tput` to get the correct escape codes. For example,

```bash
echo "$(tput setaf 5)My text$(tput sgr0)"
```

outputs `My text` in a pink-ish tone.

This works fine on Linux, macOS, FreeBSD, NetBSD, and Solaris. On OpenBSD 7.2, however, I get the following error:

```
tput: not enough arguments (3) for capability `setaf'
```

According to [the OpenBSD docs of `tput`](https://man.openbsd.org/tput), the attribute should be defined in `terminfo` or `termcap`. I don't see `setaf` defined in [the docs for `termcap`](https://man.openbsd.org/termcap.5), so I assume `tput` interprets `setaf` as defined in [the docs for `terminfo`](https://man.openbsd.org/terminfo.5). According to those docs:

> To change the current foreground or background color on a Tektronix-type terminal, use **setaf** (set ANSI foreground) and **setab** (set ANSI background) or **setf** (set foreground) and **setb** (set background). These take one parameter, the color number.

This conflicts what I've been told by the error message. On the other hand, I can use `tput setaf 5 0 0` and, regardless of the last two parameters, the foreground colour is changed to pink-ish.

Why does `tput` require three parameters on OpenBSD, and what do those extra two parameters mean?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate (I recall it being answered before).  It's a [known bug](https://gitlab.com/jschx/ufetch/-/merge_requests/61) in the OpenBSD copy of tput.  Perhaps someday OpenBSD will [upgrade](https://www.mail-archive.com/bugs@openbsd.org/msg15988.html), and fix its [problems](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-openbsd.html#issue_tput).

Answer (score 1):

Standard expectations from as far back as I can remember using `tput` on a variety of UNIX-type systems (two decades? probably more) are:

- The `tput setaf` requires a single number following that indicates the ANSI colour number to use. *Anything else is likely to be a bug.*
- `tput sgr0` requires no parameter.
- You can chain them (`tput setaf 5 sgr0`) but this particular construct would make no sense as you would be issuing a colour change that was immediately reset.

In your situation I would reiterate that `tput setaf` requiring more than one number *is likely to be a bug*.

On my Debian-based system (bullseye) I have found that `tput setaf 5 0 0` is accepted, with the unexpected trailing values ignored (no error), so you might be able to satisfy the OpenBSD bug without breaking other systems. (The same applies for other `tput` commands: additional trailing arguments are accepted but ignored.) However, if this isn't always the case, code like this might provide a suitable but necessary workaround:

```
# Work around OpenBSD bug https://gitlab.com/jschx/ufetch/-/merge_requests/61
tputbug=; tput setaf 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 || tputbug='0 0'

tput setaf 2 $tputbug
```

As an aside, if you were going to use lots of colour codes my recommendation would be to capture them in variables so that the command execution was performed once per colour rather than once per line:

```
magenta=$(tput setaf 5 $tputbug)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

echo "${magenta}My text${normal}"
```

Further note for other readers: variables don't normally require curly braces (`$magenta` is quite acceptable) but in this case they are used to separate the variable name from the immediately following text. Otherwise you would have an unset variable called `$magentaMy`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `tput setaf sgr0` is just a typo from when I wrote the question (I fixed the question now), I can confirm that the bug is indeed specifically due to `tput setaf 1`, because running only that command on the command line gives me the indicated error. It makes sense that it's an error, but OpenBSD is probably the Unix I used the least, so I started by assuming I made a mistake. And thank you for the suggestion of re-using `tput` output, though in my case the output is used only once ^^

Comment: Thank you for the update! Simply using all three arguments indeed works on both OpenBSD and Debian Bookworm, but on Debian Testing it gives me the error `tput: unknown terminfo capability '0'`. And unfortunately, I agree with that error, because `tput` allows you to specify multiple commands in sequence: `tput setaf 5 0 0` is like `tput setaf 5` followed by `tput setaf 0 0`, and that second command is not valid :-(

Comment: @FWDekker there you go. Another proposal, tested as best I can given I don't have Bookworm

Comment: Oh nice, that's creative. I had [written my own answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735999/), and while I saw one other solution checking the error output of `tput`, I think yours is much shorter and more elegant :-)

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Dickey pointed out in [his comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735925/#comment1397239_735925) to this question, this is a known bug where `tput` incorrectly calculates the required number of arguments, [which has already been reported to OpenBSD](https://www.mail-archive.com/bugs@openbsd.org/msg18443.html); this is in addition to [several other problems with OpenBSD's `tput`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-openbsd.html#issue_tput) which basically result from OpenBSD's `tput` [being outdated](https://www.mail-archive.com/bugs@openbsd.org/msg15988.html).

It looks like this bug has been encountered many times before by others ([[1]](https://gitlab.com/jschx/ufetch/-/merge_requests/61) [[2]](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/245) [[3]](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/727) [[4]](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/issues/829) [[5]](https://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=11594)). Obviously, the correct solution would be to fix this bug in OpenBSD, but I don't have the know-how to do that.

I've seen three possible workarounds:

- Stuart Henderson [recommended in the OpenBSD mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/bugs@openbsd.org/msg15989.html) to use `tput setaf 5 0 0` as a workaround, where the last two arguments are bogus. This works fine on OpenBSD, but results in errors on other systems, meaning that you'd have to detect OpenBSD and dynamically change how you invoke `tput`.
- Set `TERM=xterm` if you detect OpenBSD is running. The drawback is that OpenBSD users have only 8 colours.
- Check if `tput setaf 5` returns an error, and change how you invoke `tput` depending on that.

In my case, I'll not spend any effort trying to work around or fix the issue. If a user of mine encounters this issue, they can choose to disable the colour feature of my program, revive the bug report on OpenBSD, or try to fix the bug in OpenBSD themselves.